# Complete the matrix through a rank-one approximation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank, linear-approximation

Complete the matrix through a rank-one approximation:

\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&?\end{pmatrix}

I am new to these types of problems, therefore a detailed explanation would really be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by completing the matrix through a rank-one approximation?

Comment: @induction601: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion#Low_rank_matrix_completion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to find a matrix $X$ such that $X_{11} = 1$, $X_{12} = 2$, $X_{21} = 3$, and $\operatorname{rank} X = 1$.

**Hint**: What do the vectors $(1,2)$ and $(3,6)$ have in common? (drawing these vectors might help)

Comment: Vectors (1, 2) and (3, 6) and multiples of each other. So is the missing element 6? That seems way too easy.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thanks @parsaid